# Custom camera Android - Loading placeholder

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I have implemented a custom camera application in Android following the guide from [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera). I start the camera from another activity. There is a significant delay (several seconds) from clicking the start camera button to my custom camera UI showing (the previous activity UI remains displayed). The custom camera UI is not complicated, it is primarily just the camera preview. There is some other stuff going on whilst the camera is loading, but I have moved most of it to another thread.

I grab a Camera object using:

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        if (ConfigData.debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "* getCameraInstance Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

I link this to a MediaRecorder and SurfaceView using:

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

// Preview
SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
```

,

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    params = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes!=null) {
        // set the focus mode
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

        } else if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY)) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);

        }
    }

    isZoomSupported = params.isZoomSupported();

    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    try {
        mCamera.unlock();
        startRecording();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and:

```
/** Start recording video */
private void startRecording() throws IOException {
    try {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        setMediaProfile();

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();

        mMediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

From my experimentation, commenting various sections, the lag seems to be coming from my "startRecording" function. Commenting the function, the UI loads instantly, however the preview isn't loading in that case.

My main priority is to show the camera UI as soon as possible, whether the preview has loaded or not. Is there something I can do to allow the new activity to load faster? Can I move loading the camera preview to a separate thread? Anything to stop the UI from freezing on the previous activity?

Comment: You could post a message with a half-second delay, and start recording when it's received.  That would at least get the preview on screen.  Weird that it's taking so long to start recording.

Comment: You can look [my project][1].Its a custom camera app.


  [1]: https://github.com/devcelebi/Kut-Camera